# R how to get the function definition when call inside other function

Tags: r, function, call, genetic-algorithm

```
result <- .Call("mcga", popsize, chsize, crossprob, mutateprob, 
    elitism, minval, maxval, maxiter, par, best, evalFunc, 
    population, costs, envv, PACKAGE = "mcga")
```

how to get the `mcga` function definition in R, `mcga` is a R package for genetic algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Call`is used to call compiled code (dll or equivalent). The only way is to retrieve the source package (the .tar.gz), uncompress and have a look at the source code -- Cf https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcga/index.html; uncompress and have a look at "src" folder (seems to be C code in that case)

Comment: @Fiona_Wang I am the package owner, what do you want to do with the source? Please let me know if you have new ideas. Please use the version 3.0 operators with the GA::ga optimizer.

Comment: cause i tried to use this method on a regression model, but it didn't return a ideal result, example as :   x = seq(10)
y = x + x^2 + runif(10)

f<-function(a){
    return (y-(a[1]+ a[1]*x + a[2]*x^2))
}
m <- mcga(   popsize=200, 
             chsize=3, 
             minval=0.0, 
             maxval=300, 
             maxiter=500, 
             crossprob=0.5,
             mutateprob=0.01, 
             evalFunc=f)
print(m$population[1,])

Answer (score 1):

You can get the definition of the function at the GitHub page of the package:
https://github.com/cran/mcga/blob/master/src/mcga.c

Regards,
J_F